# Vue router guard beforeEach store user location before login and redirect after. What is right way to implement?

Tags: vue-router

I'm using vue router with quasar framework. Here is my route guard at beforeEach hook:

```
let storedURL = null
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const record = to.matched.find(record => record.meta.auth)
    if (record) {
      if (store.getters['auth/check']) {
        if (storedURL) {
          const redirectURL = storedURL
          storedURL = null
          next(redirectURL)
        } else {
          next()
        }
      } else {
        storedURL = to.path
        next('/')
      }
    } else {
      if (to.path === '/' && store.getters['auth/check']) {
        next('/dashboard')
      } else {
        next()
      }
    }
  })
```

It works but throws an error when store location:

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
notify@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:730:36
reactiveSetter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1056:11
proxySetter@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4625:5
__onControlFocusin@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/quasar/src/components/field/QField.js:345:9
invokeWithErrorHandling@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1853:26
invoker@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2178:14
add$1/original._wrapper@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:6907:25
```

and when redirects:

```
uncaught exception: undefined
```

Without this guard there are no errors. But I can't understand what is wrong with my code. Thanks for help!

Comment: timeout meanning that you make infinite loop in your guard

Comment: Try to add `return` for each next method to end the function

Comment: @Joseph thanks, but it makes no difference with or without return... Even more if I leave inside only redirect for unauthorized users it works without errors with simple ```next()```